# How to change Instagram account to email sign-in from Facebook sign-in?

Tags: instagram, instagram-account

I used Facebook to create an Instagram account. However, I want to disable my Facebook account but continue to use Instagram with my current account.

How can I change my Instagram account to use an email sign-in rather than signing in with Facebook?

Comment: try adding your email from https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/ and then change your password from https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/change/

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Instagram profile and click on [Edit Profile](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/).

Enter the **Email** address you wish to use for login (and make sure you have access of this email), set a **Username** (you can use your username instead of email id with password to login your account).

Now go to https://www.instagram.com and tap **Forgot?** next to Password on the log in screen to [reset your password](https://help.instagram.com/374546259294234/):

> - To reset through your email address, tap **Username or Email**, enter your username or the email address you used to create your account and tap search. Choose **Send a Password Reset Email**.
> - To reset through Facebook, tap **Reset using Facebook**. You may be asked to log into Facebook. You can then enter a new password for the Instagram account that was most recently linked to your Facebook account.
>
> Note: If you can't access the email you registered with and you didn't link your Instagram account to Facebook, we're not able to give you access to this account.

After resetting your password you can disable you Facebook account or you can [unlink](https://help.instagram.com/536741816349927) your Facebook account from Instagram first and then disable your Facebook account.